# How do I view Facebook "Review Recent Activity" window and why can't I see the IP address of suspicious logins?

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-account

I previously asked a question about finding the ip of recent logins to my facebook account.  It seems like facebook does not release this information.

However, I came across this:
[image]

How does this screen come up?  Shouldnt I be able to see the IP address of the suspicious login on step 3?  Or does this only show up if the "hacker" tried to login but was unsucessfull?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this screen shows up when a very long distance is travelled and the user logs in via a different ip. Here are the two cases I have encountered.

**2500 miles Montreal,Qc,Canada to Trinidad and Tobago,Caribbean**
I was helping my sibling (in Trinidad and Tobago) with a problem on Facebook from Montreal,QC by logging into his account.

**2300 miles approx Montreal,Qc,Canada to Portland,OR USA**
Visited a friend and logged in via his computer.

So with these two cases I believe its based on time/distance between places. If I log in at place X but then log in to place Y only Z minutes after (first case) miles away (second case) then I receive the verification process. This only works on the initial log in. Any activity that follows seems to be okay for me.

You can see the most recent activity information in your [settings](https://register.facebook.com/editaccount.php?settings) under Account security. In this tab it shows information for activity of users (under the assumption that all users are yourself under different locations/IP) that have logged in successfully and accessed your page.

Comment: When you encountered it, did it stop you from logging in completely? Or did it still let you through, that part wasn't really clear to me.

Comment: Well I never failed/try to fail the verification step so it let me through. My sibling helped me through his verification as he knew the pictures.

Comment: Ah, but it made you verify before you got access. Cool

Comment: I think phwd is correct, I saw that info in Facebook when I was working with a customer whose VPN connected me to Colorado while I was working from Mexico. When switching between the VPN network and other network, the IPs were logged in Facebook.